# Emacs, .historian and root user

Tags: emacs-daemon, sudo

I use the following alias:

```
alias e='emacsclient -a '\'''\'' -t
alias sudo='sudo '
```

That way I can execute both, commands and aliases, with `sudo`, including `e`, which launchs the emacs server if it is not launched yet.

The thing is that, if I have the `emacs-daemon` running, for example because I have edited a file before, and then I open the editor with `sudo`, every file which is written by the server, like `.historian`, changes its owner to `root`. So, when trying to launch the server again, the server is launched but the client doesn't show up (it frozes just after launching the server) and I have to open the client in another terminal, but emacs doesn't behave correctly anyway. For example, the minibuffer is incorrectly displayed for commands that requires input, like C-x C-f.

How can I solve that situation? How could I launch an emacs server per user basis? Or there's any other solution?e

Comment: n.b. You're missing a final `'` on your `alias e` definition -- but also, `alias e="emacsclient -a '' -t"` is a *much* simpler way to write that.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I use to edit files as root using a single running emacs daemon:

```
export EDITOR="emacsclient --tty --create-frame"
alias e="$EDITOR"
alias E=sudoedit
```

Answer (score 0):

Provisionally, I have end up with the following function bound to `C-x C-F`:

```
(defun reopen-with-sudo ()
   (interactive)
   (if buffer-file-name
       (counsel-find-file
          (concat "/sudo:root@localhost:" buffer-file-name))
     (counsel-find-file (concat "/sudo:root@localhost:"
                           (ido-real-file-name "File:")))))
```

which solves the problem without any apparent downside, except that the file will be opened twice in two different buffers.

Comment: You could use `find-alternate-file` to reuse just a single buffer for the file.